# Why is X11 forwarding allowed even though I excplicitly disabled it?

Tags: ssh, x11

I've been hardening SSH but, for some odd reason, `X11Forwarding` stays enabled. I tried adding `X11UseForwarding no`, but running `sudo sshd -T | grep x11` resulted in the error below, so I removed it:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 134: Bad configuration option: X11UseForwarding
/etc/ssh/sshd_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

Output of `sudo sshd -T | grep x11`:

```
x11displayoffset 10
x11maxdisplays 1000
x11forwarding yes
x11uselocalhost yes
```

Contents of my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.104 2021/07/02 05:11:21 dtucker Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

# To modify the system-wide sshd configuration, create a  *.conf  file under
#  /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/  which will be automatically included below
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

# If you want to change the port on a SELinux system, you have to tell
# SELinux about this change.
# semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp #PORTNUMBER
#
#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

LoginGraceTime 20
PermitRootLogin no
#StrictModes yes
MaxAuthTries 3
MaxSessions 1

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosUseKuserok yes

# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#GSSAPIEnablek5users no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the KbdInteractiveAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via KbdInteractiveAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and KbdInteractiveAuthentication to 'no'.
# WARNING: 'UsePAM no' is not supported in Fedora and may cause several
# problems.
#UsePAM no

AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding no
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
ClientAliveInterval 300
ClientAliveCountMax 1
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

# custom ssh settings
AllowUsers [REDACTED]
```

Comment: `X11UseForwarding` is not `X11Forwarding`.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Yes, I thought so. I just found an answer on askubuntu where it said you could add `X11UseForwarding`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true there is `X11Forwarding no` in the config file, but there's also `Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf` before it. For each keyword (like `X11Forwarding`) the *first* obtained value is used (`man 5 sshd_config` states this explicitly). This means if `X11Forwarding yes` from some `.conf` file in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/` applies then the value will be `yes`.

Check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf` files. Useful command:

```
grep -il X11Forwarding /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
```

If you want `X11Forwarding no` to take precedence, place it early in the main config file, certainly before the `Include` line.

Comment: You were right! There's a file called `50-redhat.conf` where a couple of the options I had explicitly disabled in the main conf were enabled. I have disabled them inside the same file and now everything works as expected. Much obliged!

Answer (score 0):

As Giles says you seem confused about the configuration directive. Your output from 'sshd -T` says there is an error at line 134 - but you only showed us the first 133 lines of config. Conversely, your grep statement says that the "Bad configuration option: X11UseForwarding" is not present in the file you grepped.

I think you need you go back and establish exactly what is in your config files and do an explicit restart on the sshd service to ensure it is running with the current config from the file.

Comment: I apologise. I removed line 134 (`X11UseForwarding`) since it gave me an error; I fixed the post now to clear it up.